# CSS - don't allow word to be sliced

Tags: css, word-wrap

For example I don't want that the word **“Call”** to be sliced in **“Ca

ll”**, but I want to apply 'white-space:wrap;'

```
//'float:left;' it place the text next to the image.
<div style="float:left;"><img  src="img.jpg" /></div>
<div style="color:gray;word-wrap:normal;white-space: wrap;">Why my text is sli
ced. </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the rule you're looking for but see how it works in conjuction with your other styles.

```
word-break: keep-all;
```

Other values are normal (only breaks on spaces and hyphens) and break-all (the line will break at any character)

```
<div style="color:gray;word-wrap:normal;white-space:wrap;word-break:keep-all;">
    Why my text is sliced.
</div>
```

On another note - in your question you actually have a line break within the word - the browser has no way of knowing this isn't two words and will always break there if needed. Are you pasting text in from a document that is entering line breaks when it wraps your text to a new line perhaps?

Comment: Hey, thanks! Style for the container was word-break: break-all;  word-wrap: break-word;You can imagine this? I did a few hours all the combinations without to think at thïs.